How to get the ROOT dir/url of a WordPress plugin from other included files?
I can get the dir/url of a plugin's file by using:
            $plugin_dir_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
            $plugin_dir_url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);

However, if the file calling the above codes are in a subdir such as ./includes, the the subdir will also be returned, like this:
/xxx/wp-content/plugins/file-converter/includes/

How to get the root dir of the plugin without the subdir? i.e. /xxx/wp-content/plugins/file-converter/

There are many ways to handle that. 
I noticed that WordPress plugins use constants to set those in the main plugin file, like:
defined( 'FILE_CONVERTER_DIR_PATH' ) || define( 'FILE_CONVERTER_DIR_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );
defined( 'FILE_CONVERTER_DIR_URL' ) || define( 'FILE_CONVERTER_DIR_URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) );

Then you can use directly FILE_CONVERTER_DIR_PATH or FILE_CONVERTER_DIR_URL constants from any included plugin PHP file, to retrieve the right main directory path or directory URL.

in my plugin, a create these hooks in the main file :
add_filter("MY_PLUGIN/root_extension", function ($r) {
    return __DIR__;
});
add_filter("MY_PLUGIN/url_extension", function ($r) {
    return plugins_url("", __FILE__);
});

and then I can use them in all my files with this code :
$url_extension = apply_filters("MY_PLUGIN/url_extension", NULL);
$root_extension = apply_filters("MY_PLUGIN/root_extension", NULL);

